# Browserify, minifyify, conditional compilation

Tags: javascript, browserify, bundling-and-minification, conditional-compilation, uglifyjs

### TL;DR

minifyify (*the Browserify plugin*) makes use of **uglify-js** but appears to be unable to handle **[Conditional compilation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#conditional-compilation)**:

- compression works
- uglifyjs alone works for conditional compilation
- minifyify provides additional compilation optimization but I have been unable to use conditional compilation with it

---

I'm using **Browserify** with the **babelify** transformer and the **minifyify** plugin. Here is the cmd, broken down in readable parts:

`browserify 
src/scripts/app/index.js 
-o 
build/prod/public/assets/js/appBundle.min.js 
-t 
[ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] 
-p 
[ minifyify --no-map --uglify [ --compress [ --drop_console --dead_code --conditionals --unused --if_return ] --mangle --screw-ie8 --define [ DEBUG=false ] ] ]`

I've gotten every setting/option to work. However, **I am unable to get conditional compilation to work**.
Minifyify uses uglifyjs' `minify` method. The fact I'm passing by minifyify shouldn't really change anything.

### Building directly through uglifyjs works

`uglifyjs input.js --compress --dead_code --define DEBUG=false -o output.js`

But then I lose the additional compressions/optimizations provided by minifyify.

**I'm also open to another build process. My needs are resumed in the settings of the current process:**

- CommonJS required modules
- transpiling of ES6 to ES5
- advanced minification/compression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the culprit was, more or less, **uglifyjs**. The property name for global definition in the task is different between CMD and Programmatic API.

- **cmd line**: `--define VARNAME=VALUE`
- **programmatic**: `compress: {global_defs: { varname: value } }`

That being said, it also seems that **minifyify** or **browserify** isn't passing the cmd-line options properly for global definitions - *we're still investigating this*

### programmatic solution

By using the Browserify & minifyify programmatic API, the build task works. Below is the same task as the one in OP, but it works:

```
"use strict";
var browserify = require("browserify"),
    fs = require("fs");

browserify("src/scripts/app/index.js")
    .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"], plugins: ["transform-object-assign"]})
    .plugin("minifyify", {map: false, uglify: {
        compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            dead_code: true,
            conditionals: true,
            unused: true,
            if_return: true,
            global_defs: {
                DEBUG: false
            }
        },
        mangle: true,
        "screw-ie8": true
    }})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("build/prod/public/assets/js/appBundle.js"));
```

#### update in uglifyjs docs

I've proposed a modification to the current uglifyjs docs, providing an example using the programmatic API as above, so as to avoid this issue for others in the future.